# Anonymous semaphore in Win API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have 2 processes which are running on the same Windows machine. Both of them are using semaphores that are provided from [`CreateSemaphore()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createsemaphorew), and these 2 semaphores are created with the `lpName` parameter set to `NULL` (0).

Do these 2 processes share the same semaphore object? Or are anonymous semaphores unique in the OS?

Comment: Each call to `CreateSemaphore` with no name creates a new, separate semaphore.

Comment: Synchronization primitives that have no name are always local-only.

Comment: every no-name object is unique - you create new object every time when create it without name

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - what you mean under *local-only* ?

Comment: Sometimes unnamed semaphore can be shared by using inheritable handle. [How to pass handle to child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420508/how-to-pass-handle-to-child-process)

Comment: @DanielSęk - or by duplicate handle too

Comment: They are not automatically shared. Named priminitives are automatically shared between whoever application knows the name and has the permissions.